# How to order the ngrams in Google's database (or the one hosted on AWS) by frequency

Tags: database, hadoop

I'm looking for a way to order Google Book's Ngram's by frequency.

The original dataset is here: http://books.google.com/ngrams/datasets. Inside each file the ngrams are sorted alphabetically and then chronologically.

My computer is not powerful enough to handle 2.2 TB worth of data, so I think the only way to sort this would be "in the cloud".

The AWS-hosted version is here: http://aws.amazon.com/datasets/8172056142375670.

Is there a financially efficient way to find the 10,000 most frequent 1grams, 2grams, 3grams, 4grams, and 5grams?

To throw a wrench in it, the datasets contain data for multiple years:

```
As an example, here are the 30,000,000th and 30,000,001st lines from file 0 
of the English 1-grams (googlebooks-eng-all-1gram-20090715-0.csv.zip):

circumvallate   1978   313    215   85 
circumvallate   1979   183    147   77

The first line tells us that in 1978, the word "circumvallate" (which means 
"surround with a rampart or other fortification", in case you were wondering) 
occurred 313 times overall, on 215 distinct pages and in 85 distinct books 
from our sample.
```

Ideally, the frequency lists would only contain data from 1980-present (the sum of each year).

Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using [Pig](http://pig.apache.org/)!

Pig makes things like this very easy and straight-forward. Here's a sample pig script that does pretty much what you need:

```
raw = LOAD '/foo/input' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (ngram:chararray, year:int, count:int, pages:int, books:int);
filtered = FILTER raw BY year >= 1980;
grouped = GROUP filtered BY ngram;
counts = FOREACH grouped GENERATE group AS ngram, SUM(filtered.count) AS count;
sorted = ORDER counts BY count DESC;
limited = LIMIT sorted 10000;
STORED limited INTO '/foo/output' USING PigStorage('\t');
```

Pig on AWS Elastic MapReduce can even operate directly on S3 data, so you would probably replace `/foo/input` and `/foo/output` with S3 buckets too.